# Error with custom Search and Replace function for Google Sites

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use a script to replace a particular string with a different string. I think the code is right, but I keep getting the error "Object does not allow properties to be added or changed."

Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

```
function searchAndReplace() {
  var teams = SitesApp.getPageByUrl("https://sites.google.com/a/directory/teams");
  var list = teams.getChildren();

  list.forEach(function(element){
    page = element.getChildren();
  });

  page.forEach(function(element) {
    var html = element.getHtmlContent();
    html.replace(/foo/, 'bar');
    element.setHtmlContent = html;
  });

};
```

Comment: At what line are you getting this error?

Comment: Unfortunately, the error does not specify a line. I don't think it's a compiling issue. I'm not a professional programmer, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

[Javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):
The replace() method returns a **new string** with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement.

I think the issue here is that forEach cannot change the array that it is called upon.  From developer.mozilla.org "forEach() does not mutate the array on which it is called (although callback, if invoked, may do so)."

Try doing it with a regular loop.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm getting the same error.